# Misplacement of the ticks on the secondary x-axis in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a time series with labels corresponding to GMT time at the bottom and local time (GMT-7) at the top between Julian Days 128 and 158. I am using twiny() to create the secondary x-axis but somehow the labels on it are not placed properly. How can I fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

dayTickLocations=range(128*24,158*24,24)
dayTickLabels=range(128,158)

dayTickLocations_loc=range((128*24)-7,(158*24)-7,24)
dayTickLabels_loc=range(128,158)

ax1.set_xlim(128*24,158*24)
ax1.set_xlabel('Julian Days (GMT Time)')
ax1.set_xticks(dayTickLocations)
ax1.set_xticklabels(dayTickLabels)
ax1.grid(True)

ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_xlabel('Julian Days (Local Time)')
ax2.set_xlim(128*24,158*24)
ax2.set_xticks(dayTickLocations_loc)
ax2.set_xticklabels(dayTickLabels_loc)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of the commands in the 'ax2' block somehow solved the problem, though I don't understand how.

```
ax2.set_xlabel('Julian Days (Local Time)')
ax2.set_xticks(dayTickLocations_loc)
ax2.set_xticklabels(dayTickLabels_loc)
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_xlim(128*24,158*24)
```